# Android apps for un-root phone to capture network packets without interrupt Internet connection

Tags: packet-capture

Tried the tPacketCapture app, and could not access Internet when the tPacketCapture app is enabled and monitoring the network.

Is there any Android apps for un-root phone (phone that is not rooted) that is able to capture network packets without causing interruption (and without causing one to be unable to access Internet?)

Preferably the Android apps is free to download and use.

Comment: Does "un-root" mean "rooted" or "non-rooted"?

Comment: I used tPacketCapture and had no issue with interruption. Maybe you are usually using a VPN or proxy to access the internet? (since tPacketCapture acts as a VPN so it might interfere with other VPNs.)